# Proper use of element.all & .get() with page objects

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, pageobjects

I have noticed that if I am using element.all & get() with page objects that if I put the get() on the page object side it works but if I move it to the spec side it does not work. For example take this element locator.

```
element.all(by.repeater('some_element'));
```

If I want to select the first item in this element array. I can write the page object like this:

```
==mypage.js==
this.myfoo = element.all(by.repeater('some_element')).get(0);
```

And then call it from my spec like this and it will get the first element in the array.

```
==myspec.js==
mypage.myfoo;
```

The above works fine, But it does not work if I move the .get(0) to the spec side and remove it from the page object side.

```
==mypage.js==
this.myfoo = element.all(by.repeater('some_element'));


==myspec.js==
mypage.myfoo.get(0);
```

Anyone know why? Is it just better programming to have it on the page object side? I don't mind using it the way it is working. I'm just curious why it doesn't work if I use the .get() on the spec side.

Comment: try wrapping this,myfoo in function such as function getElement(index){
return element.all(by.repeater('some_element'))(index)
}

Comment: It should work @Dennis because when you use `element.all().get()` protractor doesn't get the element until and unless you call an operation on top of it. Can you show how you are trying to export the mypage module? And what version of protractor are you using?